# Mysql select 3 entries, skip next two, select next 3 etc

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from mysql like this: select 3 entries, skip the next 2 and so on. Is this possible with `mod,id` ? Or what would be the best possible way to do it ?

(I don't delete any entries ever, so the order won't be a concern)

//Edit: Thinking of something like `select * from table where id mod 4 <> 0` which would skip the 4th, any way to also make it skip the 5th ?

Comment: What's the frequency of this query in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ... 
 WHERE MOD(...,5) NOT IN (4,0);
```

?

Comment: My example table has 44 entries, using this query it selects 43, expected result is 26 though.

Comment: correction: If I run this in phpmyadmin this does indeed show 26 also in the order that I require, running that on my site shows me 43 though ?

Comment: Well this works the way I want it. @Strawberry Would you mind telling me, what would be the opposite of this query, meaning skip 1,2,3 selecting 5,6 skip 7,8,9 select 10,11... and so on.

Comment: Marius, assuming that by 'the opposite' you actually mean 0,4,5,9,10,14,15..., then you really should be able to figure that out for yourself by reference to the example already provided!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to add **one** more column, and **update** it on **insert** (1,2,3...), and then use **WHERE** clause.

Make things more simple.

And don't forget to add **index** on this column